# how do i plot training results in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am fairly new to python and i am trying to plot the training set results and the test set results in a graph

[image]

This diagram shows the results from comparing the y_test and y_predicted. i used the following code to plot this

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
ax.plot(range(len(y_test)), y_test, '-b',label='Actual')
ax.plot(range(len(y_pred)), y_pred, 'r', label='Predicted')
plt.show()
```

Now i want to have the extact same graph for my training data. how do i generate this?

Comment: train model with training data and test with training data and draw the graph:)

Comment: @ZestyDragon can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example: using random forest**

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5,random_state=0)
clf.fit(train_x,train_y)
pred_random = clf.predict(test_x)
pred_random2 = clf.predict(train_x)
```

for plotting graph of test

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 10))
ax1 = sns.distplot(test_y, hist=False, color="r", label="Actual Value")
sns.distplot(pred_random, hist=False, color="b", label="Fitted Values" , ax=ax1)
plt.title('DIST PLOT Random Forest')
plt.xlabel('')
plt.ylabel('')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

for plotting graph of train

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 10))
ax1 = sns.distplot(train_y, hist=False, color="r", label="Actual Value")
sns.distplot(pred_random2, hist=False, color="b", label="Fitted Values" , ax=ax1)
plt.title('DIST PLOT Random Forest')
plt.xlabel('')
plt.ylabel('')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```